# TransactionScope revert stored procedure changes

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, stored-procedures, transactionscope

I am using `TransactionScope` with a stored procedure, which itself is not using transactions, but after completing transaction scope, changes made in the stored procedure are reverted. I can't understand what is the issue.

This is my code:

```
using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, TransactionOptionConstant.option1)) 
{
    // Call stored procedure
    transactionScope.Complete();
}
```

Comment: If there is any error in SP are you issuing a rollback from the SP

Comment: How do you call SP?

Comment: I got the issue of reverting changes, there is one code which is called in parallel, which reverts the changes

Comment: which one ORM do you use??

Comment: We are using Dapper

Answer (score 1):

It is very difficult to debug without seeing the actual code (stored procedure, the code that calls it and the rest of the surrounding code. Some hints from me.

Surround your code with try catch:

```
try 
{
    using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, TransactionOptionConstant.option1)) 
    {
        //Call Stored Procedure 
        transactionScope.Complete();
    }
} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{
   // Make sure you never reach this when you call complete.
}
```

[Check the following from Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transactionscope.complete?view=netframework-4.8)

> The actual work of commit between the resources manager happens at the End Using statement if the TransactionScope object created the transaction.

The commit is not happening if the exit using does not occur.

#### Inspect your stored procedure

Maybe your stored procedure does not actually save the changes. This was also added by a comment but it can very well be that it's some exception caught on the SQL Server side of things that is handled there and not propagated back to the code.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you need to create a new connection and execute your operations with that in order to execute the transaction.I'm assuming you have a baseRepository that gives you a `CreateConnection`.

I think the following code can help you

```
using (TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope(scopeOption: TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, asyncFlowOption: TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
    {
        var dbConn = _baseRepository.CreateConnection(); 
        //use dbConn to Call Stored Procedure
        transactionScope.Complete();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You create scope with option `TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew`. So, your SP can be executed in different transaction.

Try to set option `TransactionScopeOption.Required`.